# How to do load testing in real browsers[Not HTTP based load testing like JMeter] in testcafe?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

We are using testcafe for end to end testing,But we have one requirement like 10 different users logins simultaniously[parallelly] to different page and each user uploads different excel files.Is it possible to acheive is testcafe or any other opensource tool is available in market for load testing in real browser?

Comment: TestCafe is not really a tool for load testing. I don't recommend misusing tools for what they are not build for (even if you could technically achieve it). Perhaps you can have a look at some other tools like [k6](https://k6.io/)

Comment: thank you sir,but is their any open source tool for load testing in real browsers? K6 is similar to Jmeter like HTTP based load testing.

Comment: We are not aware of any tools that will meet your requirements.